# Could not serialize object In Mule Design - Anypoint Studio

Tags: mulesoft

[image: Here is my design]

I am using salesforce connector to Insert Opportunity in my salesforce Org.
But I am getting this error.

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not serialize object (org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException)
Transformer           : ObjectToByteArray{this=6a9344f5, name='_ObjectToByteArray', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Serializable, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mule.modules.salesforce.bulk.EnrichedSaveResult
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:133)
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.JavaObjectSerializer.doSerialize(JavaObjectSerializer.java:44)
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer.serialize(AbstractObjectSerializer.java:64)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.SerializableToByteArray.doTransform(SerializableToByteArray.java:65)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToByteArray.doTransform(ObjectToByteArray.java:78)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:406)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:354)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:743)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:209)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.doBuildResponse(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:122)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.buildResponse(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:86)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:78)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:187)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:93)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:49)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:112)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:39)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:135)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also tried debugger. And I am getting this error in Salesforce connector.

I am posting this json in http request.

```
{   "Name": "Test Opp by Local",
    "CloseDate": "11/22/2017",
    "State__c": "Prospecting"   }
```

Mapping in Transform Message:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[{
    Name: payload.Name,
    CloseDate: payload.CloseDate as :date {format: "M/d/yyyy"},
    State__c: payload.State__c
}]
```

[image]

It should insert this record in org. 
Kindly help me. 
Thanks!

Comment: FYI this [Could not serialize object](http://techqa.info/programming/question/42647744/Could-not-serialize-object--org-mule-api-serialization-SerializationException) post says "The solution is : Object to string transformer in mule" but offers no explanation of why the problem occurs or why that solution is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a Data weave with mime type Application/json and put payload as its out put after the salesforce connector and that error will get resolved.

**For you reference**:

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Response Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Your flow shoud look something like the Image attached.[image]